# online recommendation using mahout

Tags: hadoop, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender, near-real-time

How do I implement online recommendation using Mahout. i want to get recommendation from the mahout recommendation engine on real time using some mechanism like REST API.

please share me any implementation idea

Regards.

Comment: You can use prediction.io

Comment: You have to specify which algorithm You are planing to use from Mahout. Moreover, are You planing to feed recommender with new data in rela-time and expect more accurate recommendation? There is a huge difference between using memory-based ones (like knn) and model-based approach. The first one are easier to implement with real-time data updates. Model-base can be refreshed once in a while or use some dedicated techniques, i.e. fold-in for matrix factorization. For second case You can look at nice project - [Oryx2](https://github.com/OryxProject/oryx)

Comment: i want to use the second ones. recommendation using ItemSimilarity